# Angularjs share data across controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use service to share data cross controllers and it works.
First page use a controller named `ACtrl`:

```
<a ng-click='doit()'>click me</a>
```

Second page use a different controller `BCtrl`:

```
 <label>{{person.name}}</label>
```

In `doit` function, I shared an object using service. In BCtrl I get the share object ,all is fine.
But I want the second page open an another window, so I change first page as below:

```
<a ng-click='doit()' href='_blank'>click me</a>
```

Then second page doesn't work.
So how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/share-data-between-angularjs-controllers

Comment: Check this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/share-data-between-angularjs-controllers

Comment: I don't really think your problem is with sharing data between controllers.  Instead, I think your problem is with the fact that when you open a page in a new window, it is a new app, and it **cannot** communicate with the other app.  You can only share data, services, events, etc. with controllers that are in the same app (i.e. same window).

Comment: @Claies yes, you understand correctly!

Comment: @Claies I use a _blank target not self, it doesn't work. But how to solve it. My question name make a mistake.

Comment: there isn't a solution, at least not in the way you are trying.  If you target `_blank`, then you have to treat the app that loads in that new window as a separate app, and the only way to pass data to it would be by using query string parameters.

Comment: Angular is a Single Page Application, it is not a framework designed to manage more than one page in your browser simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

You can send data through events, like

ACtrl

```
data = {a: 1, b: 2}
$rootScope.$broadcast('dataChanged', data);
```

BCtrl

```
$scope.$on('dataChanged', function(e, data) {
    console.log(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly define a factory service in your service.js

```
.factory('DataScopeService', function($rootScope) {
     var mem = {};

     return {
         set: function(key, value) {
             mem[key] = value;
         },
         get: function(key) {
             return mem[key];
         }
     };
 })
```

Then, use this service to set and get data from any controller in your project.

ControllerA

```
DataScopeService.set("selectedTimePeriod", '1');
```

ControllerB

```
$scope.selectedTime = DataScopeService.get("selectedTimePeriod")
```